# Shamir Secret Sharing: I cant get the right reconstructed value in javascript

Tags: javascript, shared-secret

I try to use shamir secret sharing. I implement the code that I find in wikipedia. But when I run it, for enormous numbers the result of reconstruction is different from the real secret value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing

The reconstruction function is:

```
function join(shares) {
    var accum, count, formula, startposition, nextposition, value, numerator, denominator;
    for(formula = accum = 0; formula < shares.length; formula++) {
    for(count = 0, numerator = denominator = 1; count < shares.length; count++) {
        if(formula == count) continue; // If not the same value
        startposition = shares[formula][0];
        nextposition = shares[count][0];
        numerator = (numerator * -nextposition) % prime;
        denominator = (denominator * (startposition - nextposition)) % prime;
    }
    value = shares[formula][1];
    accum = (prime + accum + (value * numerator * modInverse(denominator))) % prime;
}
return accum;
}

var sh = split(9846513, 5, 3)
var newshares = [sh[1], sh[3], sh[4]]; 

document.write(join(newshares));

</script>
```

When I try to run this code, instead of `9846513` the result is `761`.
Can someone help me to fix this logical error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question title to be a question and not a list of keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the formula, the number your are trying to reconstruct must be less than the prime number used in the algorithm.

You must use a prime number larger that 9846513... next largest prime is 9846517

```
var prime = 9846517;
...
var sh = split(9846513, 5, 3)
var newshares = [sh[1], sh[3], sh[4]]; 
document.write(join(newshares));
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/gz84bw83/

Comment: No. There is no way to represent a number larger than the shared prime P with this secret sharing scheme.

Comment: If I try to use a very large prime number, in order to used the same number for several secret information , for example _36413321723440003717_, also i didn't get the real secret value.

Comment: You've likely exceeded largest integer allowed... Javascript will then round it to something not prime. Choose something big... but not THAT big!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answers :)

Comment: @uoyh Can you please mark my answer as the correct answer?